# Minimum and maximum of $\cos x_1+2\cos 2x_2+3\cos 3x_3$

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

Let $x_1,\dots,x_5$ be real numbers such that 
$\sum_{i=1}^5\sin x_i=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^5\cos 2x_i=-3$. What is the minimum and maximum value of $\cos x_1+2\cos 2x_2+3\cos 3x_3$?

The second condition can be rewritten using the double angle formula as $\sum_{i=1}^5\sin^2 x_i=4$. However, expressing the expression of interest $\cos x_1+2\cos 2x_2+3\cos 3x_3$ in terms of sines will leave us with square roots, which are hard to deal with in a sum like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No analytical solution, sorry! But after some trial and error, I have found:

$$F(270°, 0°, 90°, 90°, 270°) = 2$$
$$F(270°, 90°, 180°, 90°, 270°) = -5$$

The ordering of $x_4$ and $x_5$ can be interchanged.